# Is there a way to look into jvm/Clojure source code from repl?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

As some parts of Clojure are written in Java is there a way to look into these parts of source code from repl? I'm looking for something like this :

```
(source clojure.lang.Numbers/add)
```

As this part is implemented with Java 
`source` prints `Source not found` and returns `nil`.

Comment: If you use an IDE like IntelliJ, you can easily `ctrl`+`b` you way to the Java sources. That's probably easier to use and more helpful that running a command in the REPL anyway.

Comment: [javadoc](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.java.javadoc/javadoc) does not give you exactly what you're looking for, but it may help set you down the right path.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the environment you're using.
With plain REPL, you are quite limited.

Two most popular IDEs are Cursive and Emacs Cider.

As @Carcigenicate already pointed out, Cursive has an excellent Java support and allows you to jump to clojure java sources (or any other 3rd party lib sources - providing the sources have been published) easily.
It also allows you to debug Clojure compiler itself quite easily.

Emacs Cider has *some* support for Java. 
Out of the box you can jump to JDK sources (with some caveats, see https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/issues/2687).
For other artifacts (like clojure.lang itself or other 3rd party java libs) you *should* be able to jump to the source code as long as you add the corresponding **source jar** to `:resource-paths` (assuming leiningen-based project here).
See here for more info about Cider's support.